# Loop through NSArray objectAtIndex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, object, nsarray

NSInteger *count = [monLessonArrayA count];
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            arrayVar = [monLessonArrayA objectAtIndex:i];
        }

I get an error saying i is undeclared, how can I set the objectAtIndex to i so I can loop through increasing it each time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your i is undeclared.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

Also, you don't need the `*` for your `NSInteger`.

```
NSInteger count = [monLessonArrayA count];
```

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot to declare `i` (and its data type) before using it in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use fast enumeration, which is actually faster:

```
for (id someObject in monLessonArrayA) {
    // Do stuff
}
```